# Node.js - inserting dummy data into database - getting process exit code 3

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am inserting dummy data into my application's database with a single script. I am new to node.js and suspect I might be blowing stack memory...however:

I am getting a process exit code 3, which according to the documentation:

```
3 Internal JavaScript Parse Error - The JavaScript source code internal in Node's bootstrapping process caused a parse error. This is extremely rare, and generally can only happen during development of Node itself.
```

I am using 3 loops, and it's all nested callback code. Since I am new to JavaScript back-end programming, I am not sure if the stack could be the problem, but the exit code doesn't make it sound like it is a stack problem.

Here's the code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserModel = require('../models/UserModel');
UserModel.registerSchema(mongoose);
var TeamModel = require('../models/TeamModel');
TeamModel.registerSchema(mongoose);
var PlayerModel = require('../models/PlayerModel');
PlayerModel.registerSchema(mongoose);


var fs = require('fs');
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../dummy_data/dummy_player_data', 'utf8'));

var system_db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/local_dev_db');

var userz = UserModel.getNewUser(system_db).find({}, function (err, users) {

    users.forEach(function (user, userIndex) {

        var user_id = user._id.toString();
        var teamz = TeamModel.getNewTeam(system_db, user_id).find({}, function (err, teams) {
            teams.forEach(function (team, teamIndex) {


                parsedJSON.forEach(function (player, playerIndex) {

                    var Player = PlayerModel.getNewPlayer(system_db, user_id);

                    var newPlayer = new Player({
                        team_id: team._id,
                        firstName: player.firstName,
                        lastName: player.lastName,
                        hidden: player.hidden,
                        email: player.email,
                        phone: player.phone,
                        gender: player.gender,
                        age: player.age,
                        shirtNumber: player.shirtNumber
                    });

                    newPlayer.save(function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("error in player save method:", err);
                        }
                        if (result) {
                            //console.log('Added!', result);
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I am only getting the error code when I am using lots of data, so that's what makes me think it's a stack problem.  I am using Mongoose for MongoDB. Any ideas on what could be happening?

inside getNewUser, getNewTeam, getNewPlayer I have:

```
exports.getNewUser = function (system_db) {
    return system_db.model('users', userSchema);;
};

exports.getNewTeam = function (system_db,user_id) {
    return system_db.model('teams_'.concat(user_id.toString()), teamSchema);
};

exports.getNewPlayer = function (system_db,user_id) {
    return system_db.model('players_'.concat(user_id.toString()), playerSchema);
};
```

these functions are returning the mongoose model for each of user, team and player.

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: I am using node version 4.23

Comment: 4.23? You mean node v0.4.23? If so, that's ancient. The latest stable version is v0.10.34. You might try with that version and see if you experience the same problem.

Comment: Oh, there is no 1.4.23. Perhaps you're reading the npm version? Try executing `node -v` at a shell/command prompt.

Comment: mmm it's version 1.4.23.  I am on Windows 7, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: see the edits to the question for node version

Comment: See, you're executing `npm`, so it's returning the npm version. `npm` is just for managing third-party node modules (similar to apt, yum, pacman, etc.). Execute just `node -v` instead of `npm node -v`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I did node -v....I am on 0.10.31...is that that old?

Comment: what's the best way to update node? I have "npm cache clean" followed by "npm update -g"

Comment: That only updates npm, not node. The easiest way on Windows is to just go to nodejs.org and download the installer for the latest stable version (v0.10.34).

Comment: What are you doing inside getNewUser and getNewTeam?

Comment: I updated to the latest node version, still get exit code 3